# Navigating through path levels of a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, google-analytics

I am working on a website where we have different levels and sublevels. Is it possible to generate the sublevels on the fly based on level clicked.

I am working with it in a flask application.

Note : Website is connected to google analytics and has multiple levels and is impossible to do it manually.

[image: As seen in this image]

Answer (score 0):

`str.split('/')` should do the trick, when used with [Flask's request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/reqcontext/). Request's `path` holds the part after `www.example.com/`

Simple example. Note the empty first result in the returned list

```py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return 'Hello'


@app.route('/path/to/wherever')
def example():
    for p in request.path.split('/'):
        print(p)
    return str(request.path.split('/'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```